# Turf - get all features of a geojson, that are in range of a point

Tags: geojson, calculation, turfjs

I have a geojson with a couple of features, eg. a grid of streets, and would like to get all streets and other features that are in a certain radius around a certain point.

How could I do that with turf? I was thinking of looping through all the points and comparing the distance with `turf.distance(from, to, options);`.

But maybe there is a better way of doing it.

This is the base with a map in the background, but I'd like to calculate it without using any map framework.

In this exmaple here, it should return the feature of the street + the closest distance.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out and if so would you post some solution to this?

Comment: @Elijah Unfortunately I didn't find any better solution. So I did: `let centerDistance = turf.distance(centerNet, currentPosition, { units: 'meters' });` and looped through all points.

Answer (score 0):

If you can treat the features you're looking for as points (rather than lines), a fast and elegant solution would be to use [geokdbush](https://github.com/mourner/geokdbush).

Based on its documentation, it is using a fast implementation for geospatial nearest-neighbor search.

For example (assuming the center of your circle is at `[centerLong, centerLat]`):

```
const KDBush = require('kdbush');
import * as geokdbush from 'geokdbush';

getLong = (p) => p.geometry.coordinates[0];
getLat = (p) => p.geometry.coordinates[1];

//build an index from all interesting (point) features  
const geoIndex = new KDBush(interestingFeaturesGeoJson.features, getLong, getLat);

//find the nearest ones to a specific point
const nearestPoints = geokdbush.around(geoIndex, centerLong, centerLat, 
        maxFeaturesToReturn, radiusInKm);
```